# Getting Bad Request for urllib.request.urlopen(url) in Facebook Graph Api

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, urllib, spyder, bad-request

Why I am getting
`HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`
for

`url="https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/112722945449757_1009905439064832/reactions?access_token=my_accesstoken&fields=can_post%2Cid%2Clink%2Cname%2Cpic%2Cpic_crop%2Cpic_large%2Cpic_small%2Cpic_square%2Cprofile_type%2Ctype%2Cusername%2Cpicture%7Bheight%2Cis_silhouette%2Curl%2Cwidth%7D&summary=true&limit=25&after=TVRBd01EQTVPVFEwT0RJek1EQXhPakUwTmpneE9UUTFNVE02TWpVME1EazJNVFl4TXc9PQZDZD"`

This url is working perfectly fine in browser(chrome) and it is giving `HTTP Error 400: Bad Request` error while accessing through `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` in my ide(spyder) in **python 3.6**

Comment: Check what the response body contains in this case.

Comment: @CBroe Is there any limit that we can send only n number of request to graph.facebook.com within given time interval through a python script?. because this URL dose not throw any error when i am requesting after some time(30 to 40 min latter of previous erroneous request) again.

Comment: Of course there’s limitations ... most importantly, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting